# Butternut Squash - when to harvest?

Tags: harvesting, pumpkins, ripening

I think most of them are ripe now, but as I can see, they still keep growing, increasing lenght:
[image]

Should I harvest them now or I can wait? When harvested, I have no cool place for storage, so better to let them grow for now? How do you think?

From other side, I got huge mildew attack:
[image]

But as long as laves are still green, I think fruits grow anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The squash is edible (and good) at every stage from small and green to large and evenly tan amid the frost-killed leaves. As long as the green is gone, I think they are ripe enough to put away and keep well. I grow butternuts almost every year, and they always get that late-summer mildew. Mine get stored wherever there's room, and no special temperature is needed. I have 2 left from last October's harvest, they are likely a little on the dry side, but that really doesn't matter to the cooked end result.

Comment: That means they can last almost one year without any special care - good news. It's my first attempt to grow them, with pretty good result

Answer (score 6):

If the skins have firmed up enough that you can’t easily dent them by pressing your fingernail into the skin, you should be able to harvest and expect good storage times. If the skins are still very tender, you might want to keep them on the vine a bit longer.